# Google Apps Script fade in

Tags: animation, google-apps-script, slideshow, fadein

Is there a way to make an image slide show using only google apps script ui services.I have created a gallery of image but doesnt have any transition animation. I cant find any example using any effect animation (fade in fadeout). I cant also find any timed events examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, this will not be possible using the UiApp. I believe Caja rejects CSS3, so therefore you wouldn't be able to set it as an attribute either.

The only thing I can suggest is utilizing the HTML Service which would allow the use of JQuery - be sure to use Google's hosted JQuery as it will run faster for you.

Hope this helps,
Cheers.

Comment: UiApp does not use Caja, it simply does not need to as you can't use script or stylesheets there.  Only HTMLService is feed through Caja.

Comment: You are right. I don't know why I was thinking that Caja affected what style attributes that UiApp instances could take on.